# Store database in local or server

Tags: sql, database, sqlite, mobile-devices

This is the first time that I develop a mobile application and there is some data that I want to store.

But the question is where should I store the data, in local (the mobile itself) or in server ?

Furthermore, in which case and which information should I store in local and database ?

(Correct me if I understand something wrong)

Comment: Specific questions are better.  For example, "I have a mobile *banking* application, I want to store *language preferences*.  Give us a better understanding of what you need, and you'll get a better response.

Answer (score 0):

it is depend on your application. if your application is an standalone one that data is manipulated only with this device then store whole data in mobile. but in cases such as mobile banking, email, ... that data is manipulated from different devices and/or other users can affect data then you must store whole data in server and parts of them in mobile e.g. gmail application which store data for last 30 days.

Answer (score 0):

Storing data on Server means that you need to develop online application that will contact the server to get the data, where as the local database enables your app to work offline.

Does your data changed frequently? or do you want to use client's data in any way?
If the answer was yes for any question, then you have to develop online app with your data saved on server. and you can have a cached copy on a local database. otherwise, I advice to develop it offline since its development and implementation cost is much less than online app.